# ASP Net MVC - Inserir html helper em string e renderizar via Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helpers

Fala galera,

Tenho a seguinte situação: tenho uma lista de links cadastrados no banco de dados, que serão carregados de acordo com o perfil do usuário.

Atualmente estou obrigado a fazer assim:

```
@Html.Raw(listaMenusSistema[i].HtmlMenu);
```

Isso me trará o resultado:

```
<li class="teste"><a href="/">login</a></li>
```

Mas gostaria de utilizar o Html.ActionLink, para facilitar a manutenção dos links. Assim sendo eu teria no banco de dados:

```
<li class="teste">@Html.ActionLink("login", "login", "home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
```

para produzir o mesmo resultado.

Acontece que, se eu trazer do banco essa string, o razor não interpreta o html helper no meio da string, e vai gerar o html:

```
<li class="teste">@Html.ActionLink("login", "login", "home", new { area = "" }, null)"</li>
```

ao invés do correto, que seria o mesmo acima:

```
<li class="teste"><a href="/">login</a></li>
```

Alguém sabe como resolver ou tem alguma idéia ?

Valeu.

Jonas

Comment: Boa tarde, alguma idéia ? Valeu ...

Comment: Você tem que trazer na lista `listaMenusSistema` as decrições dos itens do menu e não o html do item. Ae você pode fazer um loop com `@foreach` e escrever com os `@Hmlt.ActionLink` dentro das tags <li> .